# Prevent Trigonometric simplifications from using double angle and half angle formulae?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, evaluation, trigonometry

Is there any way to force Mathematica to not use double and half angle formulae etc. when simplifying Trigonometric expressions?

For example,`Simplify[Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x])]` will give us `Tan[x/2]`. The angle `x` was changed to `x/2`.

I don't want the angle to change during simplification. So, Mathematica should not convert `x` to `2x` or `3x` or `x/2` or `x/3` etc.

Can I force Mathematica to simplify an expression under this constraint?

Answer (score 3):

You may do the following:

```
g[e_] := Count[e, x/2, Infinity];
Simplify[Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x]), ComplexityFunction -> g]

(*  Sin[x]/(1 + Cos[x])  *)
```

Though in the present case you get the same. However, in a more complex case it can help.

Have fun!

Comment: Hi @Alexei. :) Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain how the above code works?

Comment: @iKnowNothing Is there something about [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) you don't understand or is it [`Count`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count.html)?  (There are similar examples in the docs.)

Comment: I don't understand the first line. :) I understand the first line of the documentation of count. `Count[{a, b, a, a, b, c, b}, b]` but that does not clarify how the `Count` in this situation works.

Comment: The first line defines a function, g, that will be used instead of the built-in `ComplexityFunction` applied with `Simplify`. g takes an expression e and counts the number of times x/2 enters e. Infinity in the third position indicates that this should be counted on all levels of the expression.